# Input is not in correct format

Tags: c#, exception, file-io, type-conversion, runtime-error

I am trying to read in a file and then put the values into a matrix. I am receiving an error that the input sting is not in the correct format. It also has the troubleshooting tip, "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object. This is very odd since I am not even using DateTime anywhere. Below is my code. I am sure I am missing something silly. If I forgot any part of the code that you need to see, please let me know.

Code (C#):

```
class Program
{
    private static string line;
    private static int[,] matrix;
    private static int numOfCities;
    private static int startCity;
    private static int[] greedyPath;
    private static int greedyRecursionCount;
    private static int total;
    private static int lowerBoundTotal;
    private static string filename = "points.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        readTxtFile();

        getStartCity();

        greedyStart();

        totalTour();

        lowerBound();

        compareAll();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void readTxtFile()
    {
        numOfCities = 0;
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filename);
        numOfCities = int.Parse(tr.ReadLine().Trim());

        line = "1";
        int index = 0;
        matrix = new int[numOfCities,numOfCities];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCities; i++)
        {

            line = tr.ReadLine();

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfCities; j++)
            {

                matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(line[index].ToString().Trim());
                index = index + 2;

            }//end inner for loop
            index = 0;

        }//end outer for loop

        tr.Close();
    }
}
```

Content of File:

```
1000 //Number of points that are in the file
16   11 //XY-Points that are separated by 3 spaces
10   45
29   47
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since this code doesn't have any reference to `DateTime` anywhere and isn't doing any such parsing, it is not the cause of the error. Check where the exception _actually_ comes from.

Comment: Probably coming from the `int.Parse` call.

Comment: What's the exact message?  What line fails? What does the input file look like? (I assume it's failing at run time.)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. PhoenixReborn Is correct it is coming from the int.Parse line. And it is failing at runtime. The exact message is what I wrote in the question, "input sting is not in the correct format" It is reading it in write it seems, but then it is throwing that error when trying to parse it.

Comment: What are the contents of the string that are being parsed?

Comment: Well then make sure your data is good.

Comment: I will update the question to include the content

Comment: Does the data file actually contain slashes?  What happens if you remove them?

Comment: No it only contains those numbers. That was just comments.

Comment: matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(line[index].ToString().Trim()); is not doing what you think it should.  you are converting the first character to a character then string then trim then parse.  so your first conversion will be 1, then it will fail when it attempts to convert " ".  you are looking for matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(line.substring(index,2).Trim()); then index += 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(line[index].ToString().Trim());
```

is not doing what you think it should. you are converting the first character to a character then string then trim then parse. so your first conversion will be 1, then it will fail when it attempts to convert " ". you are looking for :

```
matrix[i, j] = int.Parse(line.substring(index,2).Trim());
index += 5;
```

You also need to look at your matrix.  you are creating a square matrix when it looks to need a numcities x 2.  You only have an x and y coordinate. change the inner loop to :

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
```

and adjust the matrix accordingly.

Comment: Now I am getting: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."

Comment: you are running off the end of the string.  try running in debug and step through the program.  see what index becomes when you get the error.

Comment: do you actually have 1000 cities in the text file?

Comment: Yeah I do. I figured it out. Simple error. The way you did it worked perfectly. Thank-you!

Comment: Rather than using indexes into strings, you may want to look at using Split() to break out the numbers as individual items.